# How do I prove that these two matrices' eigenvectors are the same?

Tags: matrices

$$H_{1} = \frac{T+T^{\dagger}}{2}$$
How do I prove that $H_{1}$'s eigenvectors are equal to $T$'s eigenvectors?

Comment: It would help if you gave a bit more information about what $T$ is and some context and what your notation means.

Comment: The sign dagger means complex conjugate. $T$ is a normal matrix. But I think it works for any matrix $H$ and $T$

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. In general, the eigenspaces of a matrix are different from the eigenspaces of its Hermitian part. E.g. consider
$$
T=\pmatrix{1&2\\ 0&2},\ H=\frac12(T+T^\dagger)=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&2}.
$$
$T$ has two one-dimensional eigenspaces, one spanned by $u=(1,0)^\top$ and the other spanned by $v=(2,1)^\top$. Yet, neither $u$ nor $v$ is an eigenvector of $H$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by counter-example. **General Case**

Compare $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
0&0
\end{array}\right]$ to $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
1&0
\end{array}\right]$

The first one got eigenvector $[1,0]^T$, but the second one doesn't. If you add them, $[1,0]^T$ is not an eigenvector either.

---

Will get back on the normal case later.